# How to access ignite cluster (deployed on kubernetes) using thinclient (external apps)

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I have deployed ignite cluster on kubernetes environment (GKE).
Have created k8s ingress for thinclient .

My local app needs to connect the ignite cluster using following code.

String url = ingress_url

ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses(url);

This is not working for thinClient using ignite-core and ignite-client library (version 2.14.0)

What is the right approach for external apps to access ignite cluster deployed on k8s env.

Comment: Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: @StephenDarlington: the above configuration is not working with ingress url.
(using ignite-core and ignite-client library)

Comment: What are you using for the ingress_url? It should be an hostname or IP address, not a URL.

Comment: @StephenDarlington: kubernetes env where pods can be moved between underlying servers, and where addresses can change during restarts. there is no way to provide static configuration.

Comment: Can you share your k8s configuration? It sounds like you're trying to connect to the NodePort?