# Issue in connecting remote ignite cluster using thinclient from local machine

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I have deployed single node ignite cluster on VM (Google Compute Engine).

My local app is trying to connect with this remote ignite cluster using the IP and port (thinClient).

**ClientConfiguration cfg = new    ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("vm_ip:10800");**

This is not working with the following config.

Do I need to explicitly configure something in ignite cluster to get access from remote?

Comment: It looks like firewall restriction to connect to port 10800. It worked with other vm having less restricted firewall.

Comment: How is this different from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76371115/how-to-access-ignite-cluster-deployed-on-kubernetes-using-thinclient-external)?

Comment: @StephenDarlington: the other question has ephemeral IP. as Pod is destroyable in nature in k8s environment. So accessing via LB or ingress is desirable from outside apps..
in this case, the IP is reserved for GCE instance.